# Searching ArrayList with user input

Tags: android, string, search, arraylist

Right now, I am getting a list of questions from a website and putting it inside a `ArrayList<String>`.

Now, how do I take the users input, which i converted into string (sSearchValue), and check that with the `ArrayList` to see if anything matches? And if It finds a question that contains the users search, it displays it?

```
package com.malthorn.anyquestion;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;

import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Element;
import org.jsoup.select.Elements;

import com.malthorn.gasculator.R;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Document doc;
        ArrayList<String> urls = new ArrayList<String>();
        EditText iSearchValue = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.iQuestion);
        String sSearchValue = iSearchValue.getText().toString();

        try {

            doc = Jsoup.connect("http://www.reddit.com/r/askscience/search?q=flair%3A%27Psych%27&sort=top&restrict_sr=on").get();

            Elements links = doc.select("a[href]");
            for (Element link : links) {
                String href1=link.attr("href");
                //
                if(href1.startsWith("http://www.reddit.com/r/askscience/"))
                 {
                    urls.add(link.attr("href"));
                 }

                System.out.println("\nlink : " + link.attr("href"));

            }

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public String getQuestion(String[] questions, String sSearchValue){
    for(String question : questions){
        if(question.equals(sSearchValue))
            return question;
    }

    return "";
}
```

This code searches for exact matches, if you need to find questions that ressemble the search word i would adivse you on googling the method subString for the type String and also the uses of Regex on pattern matching.

Comment: Okay thank you! From looking at my jsoup parsing, do you know if Im doing it correctly? As in, am I putting the proper data into the ArrayList?

Comment: Also, in your code, you are using string[] questions and question, can you please explain how its searching the user input if its string is sSearchValue?

Comment: The example code loops through an array of Strings (which i suppose contains the questions) and if he find one that matches the String sent (sSearchValue) he returns that question

And sorry, i'm not familiar with Jsoup parsing system ;)

Comment: But the thing Im questioning is that the question is just going to be one string value, since the user is inputting one line?

Comment: I'm confused now xD If the user inputs something, whether it's one word or a phrase, the above code will search and array of String (questions) provided by you and return the question if he finds it or an empty String if he doesnt

If you still need help please rephrase the question because i'm clearly not understanding it xD Thanks!